# RxJS: Correct way to manually emit an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Working with RxJS in Angular 4.x, I'm seeing two very different patterns for generating Observables from streams of user initiated actions. One stream is the direct result of a user clicking an 'add item' button that generates a new object. The other is a series of events issued by some third party code I'm using.

I want to be able to combine these two streams using something like 'combineLatest' to generate a single Observable.

With my button, I've followed the following pattern:

```
const signal = Observable.create(
            (observer) => {
                this.additem= (item) => observer.next(item);
            }
        );

this.item$ = signal.map((item) => [item])
                            .scan((accumulator, value) => {
                                return accumulator.concat(value);
                            });
```

However, I'm seeing a lot of information saying I should be using Subjects instead - which I am trying to use with my event callback like so:

```
sort$ = new Subject();

sortChange(sort){
        sort$.next(sort);
}
```

Then I'm attempting to combine these like this:

```
combine$ = Observable.combineLatest(sort$, item$,
                  (sort, items) => {
                      return "something that does stuff with these";}
        );
```

My questions are - what is the preferred pattern for 'manually' generating streams? Can/should observables and subjects be meshed together into a single observable like I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I think that the best source of information for this is the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/angular-2-behavior-subject-vs-observable Even if your question is not exactly a duplicate to this one to me, it feels like this answer might be what you need to make your choice.

Comment: If you want combine two Observable you can use the operator merge

Comment: I'm sorry i've been looking at your code for 2 hours now... and i am not able to understand what is ```this.item``` actually doing here?? How are you calling that function? from what i can see, you're probably trying to pass the item you create on button click to the observable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can combine Observables and Subjects into one stream.

I think the question here is what makes more sense in you usecase. From your description when implementing something like "add item" functionality I'd prefer `Subject` over `Observable.create`.

This is because every time you subscribe to your `signal` you're reassigning `this.additem`. The callback to `Observable.create` is called for every observer. Note that more correct usage of `Observable.create` would look like this:

```
const signal = Observable.create((observer) => {
   this.additem = (item) => observer.next(item);
   return () => this.additem = null;
});
```

The returned callback `() => this.additem = null` is called when you unsubscribe from this Observable and that's the place where you should handle all cleanup.

However, if you make two subscriptions to `signal` then you'll override `this.additem` twice and then if you chose to unsubscribe one of the observers you would `this.additem = null` and it would probably lead to an unexpected behavior.

So in this case it makes more sense to use `Subject`. For example like this:

```
const subject = new Subject();
this.additem = (item) => subject.next(item);
```

If you want to see more real life example of `Observable.create` have a look at for example this: [Subscribe to a stream with RxJS and twitter-stream-api module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614238/subscribe-to-a-stream-with-rxjs-and-twitter-stream-api-module/42620600#42620600)

Edit: Also have a look at these articles from the lead developer of RxJS 5:

- https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93
- https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87
- https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Pitfalls like this weren't apparent to me looking at the documentation, and I knew there had to be reasons to choose one approach over the other since both seemed to work.

Comment: @Potatoes I added a few links to articles I consider very helpful